# Vue 2 + Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo un formulario con un campo **nombre** y un `select` para **provincias**. La cuestión es que ingreso un nombre, y cuando selecciono una provincia, se me borra lo que escribí en el nombre. Y buscando y probando llegue a dar que si borro el `v-model` del `select`, ahí no se borra el nombre, pero necesito del `v-model` en el `select`.

Nombre:

```
  <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="{{old('first_name')}}"  class="form-control" placeholder="-" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="255"/>
```

Provincia:

```
 <label for="province">Provincia</label>
       <select name="province" id="province" class="form-control" v-model="province" v-on:change="getDistricts(province)">
             <option value="" hidden>-- Seleccionar --</option>    
             @foreach($provinces as $province)
                <option value="{{$province->code}}" {{ (Input::old('province') == $province->code ? "selected" : "") }}> {{$province->province}}</option>
             @endforeach                                
      </select>
```

y tengo vue definido como:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#finaldraw',
    data: {
        province: '1',
        m_district: '',
        districts: [],
        places: []
    },

    delimiters: ['<%', '%>']
});

vm.getDistricts = function (province) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/geoDistricts/getDistricts',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {province: province},
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".spinner-select i.province").css('display', 'inline-block');
            $("#district").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#place").prop('disabled', true);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(".spinner-select i.province").css('display', 'none');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#district").prop('disabled', false);
          //  vm.districts = data;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que manejes todos tus selects con la librería vue-multiselect
https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect
Te sacara de muchas broncas.

Comment: Te recomiendo [edit] tu respuesta, siguiendo esta guía: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no entiendo en que esta mal?.

Comment: Gerardo, las respuestas basadas en enlaces no se consideran respuestas con la calidad del sitio. Revisa en el enlace de mi comentario anterior la sección: _Ofrece contexto para los enlaces_. A veces, los enlaces también expiran y es posible que tu respuesta quede obsoleta.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave pienso que no tienes conocimiento de vue.js por eso piensas que mi respuesta no sirve, porque no le preguntamos al que hizo la pregunta si le sirve o no y que el decida. Yo pase por varios problemas en los campos select con vue.js y con esta librería los solucione.

Comment: Gerardo, es cierto que no conozco vue.js, pero estás confundido, mis comentarios apuntan a que **mejores** la redacción de tu respuesta. En ningún momento he dicho que tu respuesta sea incorrecta. siento el malentendido.

Comment: lo siento entendí mal tu comentario. tratare de mejorar mi redacción. saludos

Comment: Enlace roto y respuesta sin detalles. Esto es lo que pasa cuando sólo colocan enlaces, por eso el buen @MauricioAriasOlave te decía sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx eso me pasa por querer ayudar pero haber si vuelvo a escribir algo en este foro. les cuesta mucho trabajo buscar en google vue-multiselect yo que culpa tengo que ya haya cambiado la url

Comment: Lo que te diré va en buen plan: No, no tienes la culpa de que haya cambiado la URL. Eso pasa por dejar de mejorar una respuesta habiéndote indicado cómo hacerlo y por qué hacerlo, sobretodo para ayudar a quienes están pasando por lo mismo. Nada tiene que ver con las ganas de querer ayudar y si ya no deseas ayudar, no estás obligado, sólo considera que tanto StackOverflow ha beneficiado tu vida como desarrollador. Si en algún momento deseas responder alguna pregunta, considera que los enlaces pueden expirar, por eso, extraer algún ejemplo de esos enlaces beneficia a tu respuesta. Saludos bro :D

Answer (score 2):

En las opciones debes de poner :vulue="la opcion", dado que de ahí tomara el nuevo valor que tendrá el select, recuerda que cuando le pasas información dinámica a las etiquetas lo debes de hacer mediante la instancia vue, tu foreach queda de la siguiente forma.

```
@foreach($provinces as $province)
    <option :value="$province->code">
        {{$province->province}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Si me permites darte una recomendación. Yo no mezclaría blade con vue, dado que si utilizas el poder de vue es mejor utilizar los recursos del cliente para renderizar su información. Tu código lo sustituiría por.

```
<option v-for="provinces as province" :value="province->code" :key="provinces">
    {{province->province}}
</option>
```